# There is no empty cell in storage pallet rack Error in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

The first time, pallets get stored in **rack** and later on, they get picked by the resource.

Now 2nd time when pellets come to get store in the  **rack**, I get `rack full error` but there is 0 pallets in rack at that time means rack is empty.

Attaching the model images below.

**Error**

[image]

**Pallet Rack**

[image]

**Rack Store**

[image]

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send pallets from one rack to another rack directly in AnyLogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74577338/how-to-send-pallets-from-one-rack-to-another-rack-directly-in-anylogic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you didn't use a rackpick to take the pallets out of the storage... you MUST use a rackpick

Or you need to use `palletRack.remove(agent);`

If that's not the problem, then you will have give more information

Comment: i am sending pallets from one rack to another using "rack store", if I use "rackpick" then i don't get option of sending pallets from one rack to another rack directly. How i can achieve that?