# How to send pallets from one rack to another rack directly in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

Ones pallets get store in rack using `rack store` block, I can move them to new location using `rack pic`. But `rack pick` don't give any option of moving pallets to new rack directly.

**My Approach:**
One pallets get store in the rack then I use  `rack store` again instead of `rack pick` for storing pallets directly to new rack. **It did work but** now Rack cells did not get empty even I move pallets from them which shows that for making sells empty in rack I have to use `rack pick`.

**Kindly let me know how I can directly transfer pallets form one rack to an other rack?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to do so you can either:
use `palletRack.remove(agent);` at your rackstore to remove the agent from the pallet rack

or
use a rackpick to a x,y,z position that will be agent.getX(),agent.getY(), agent.getZ() and then use rackstore ... but then you might get issues if you are using resources